# Remove the word optional when assigning two variable values to label

Tags: swift

I am trying to assign the value of two values `var1` and `var2` to a label called label1.

**Before I used to assign just one of these values to label1 and also received this error so I did the following:**

```
    if let var1 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var1")
    { 
        label1.text = var1 
    }else{
    }
```

Doing this solved the issue, now I have another value that I would like to add as the text of `label1` along with `var1` like this `var1 + var2` and have both follow each other.

How can this be done?

**The second value looks like this:**

```
let var2 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var2")
```

It would look something like if var1 = ... and var2 = .. {...} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the 2nd var2 to the `if let`:

```
if let var1 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var1"), let var2 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var2") { 
    label1.text = "\(var1) \(var2)"
} else {
    // One (or both) of the two were nil. Do something else as needed
}
```

If you want to show just one of the vars if the other is nil, then break it up:

```
let var1 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var1")
let var2 = defaultValues.string(forKey: "var2")
if let var1 = var1 {
    if let var2 = var2 {
        // Both are set
        label1.text = "\(var1) \(var2)"
    } else {
        // Just var1 is set
        label1.text = var1
    }
} else if let var2 = var2 {
    // Only var2 is set
    label1.text = var2
} else {
    // Neither is set
    label1.text = "Oops!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help